# Rigid types, function types and type declarations mix causes error

Tags: haskell

I was wondering, I can use type declaration in Haskell pretty much everywhere, but sometimes it leads to a strange result

```
apply (f :: a -> b) = f
```

is fine but

```
apply f = (f :: a -> b)

Couldn't match expected type ‘a1 -> b1’ with actual type ‘p’
‘p’ is a rigid type variable bound by
the inferred type of apply :: p -> a -> b
```

And that's pretty much it. I know it's a noob question, but I can't find any explanation for this behavior.
Could someone elaborate?

I tried googling about this stuff, but search led to nowhere

Comment: This is actually a bit curious. It shouldn't really be an issue in practice, though, because you should always have a top-level signature, in this case `apply :: forall a b . (a -> b) -> a -> b` (with `-XScopedTypeVariables`). With that present, both of the definitions you've tried compile without problem.

Comment: The ability to write `apply (f :: a -> b) = f`  without `ScopedTypeVariables` seems to have appeared sometime  after GHC 8.4.4, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sigh, I can understand your confusion. This is rather cumbersome to explain, so I'll simplify a bit below.

In this part

```
apply (f :: a -> b) = ...
```

the variable `f` is a pattern argument, so the type annotation is interpreted as *providing* the type for that variable. Essentially, here we are saying "let `f` be any function of type `a->b`, for some types `a` and `b`".

By contrast, in

```
apply f = (f :: a -> b)
```

the variable `f` is an expression, and the type annotation now *requires* `f` to have that type. Essentially, we are saying "check that `f` has type `a->b` here, and abort otherwise".

However, it gets worse. What are types `a` and `b` here? Haskell, in normal circumstances, interprets the whole signature as if it were quantified over all variables. Essentially, we have

```
apply f = (f :: forall a b . a -> b)
```

So, we are actually saying "check that `f` is a polymorphic function from any type to any type". Variables `a` and `b` are termed "rigid type variables" which means "these stand for any arbitrary type, and can not be assumed to be a specific type". For example, writing `[True, False] :: forall a. [a]` raises a type error since the inferred type is `[Bool]` but the signature says that it must be a list of any type, not just `Bool`. The error will complain that the rigid `a` can not be identified with `Bool`.

This in turn copes with type inference. Type inference sees `apply f =`  and tentatively gives `f` a type variable `f :: p` where `p` is a non-rigid type variable. If the code were `apply f = f && True` then we need `p = Bool`, but that's OK because `p` is not rigid, so we can identify that.

In `apply f = (f :: forall a b . a -> b)` instead we would need `p = forall a b . a -> b` but, alas, type inference is complicated and inference algorithms do not normally allow type variables like `p` to be instantiated to polymorphic types. Hence the type error.

Enough complicated theory. What to do about this, in practice? Here's a few thumb rules.

First, it's a good idea to always provide type annotations to out top-level names:

```
apply :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
apply f = f
```

There's no need to add more annotations in this case. However, if we really want that, we can:

```
-- at the beginning of the file:
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

apply :: forall a b . (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
apply f = (f :: a -> b)
```

Using that (very common) extension, we ask Haskell to make `(f :: a -> b)` refer to the `a` and `b` defined in the line above. That no longer means `(f :: forall a b . a -> b)`. In GHC 9.* I think the extension is on by default.

Note that this is needed only when our types involve type variables. If we write `expression :: Int` we never meet such issues.

Personally, I wish Haskell98 (the first version of Haskell) always required `forall` and never automatically generalized type variables making the quantifications implicit. The current state is a bit weird, but that's the result of 20+ years of research and new extensions added on top of Haskell98 while trying to maintain (some) backward compatibility.